# How are ActiveRecord fixtures dynamically inserted into the global namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fixtures

The documentation for ActiveRecord fixtures says:

> In addition to being available in the database, the fixture's data may also be accessed by using a special dynamic method, which has the same name as the model, and accepts the name of the fixture to instantiate:

And gives this example.

```
test "find" do
  assert_equal "Ruby on Rails", web_sites(:rubyonrails).name
end
```

How exactly does Ruby on Rails insert "web_sites" into the namespace like that? I am reading the documentation and the source code in lib/active_record/fixtures.rb, and I cannot figure it out.

I ask because (and maybe there is another way to do this), I am working on an application that has a lot of fixtures and is slow, and I would like a way to dynamically load fixtures before one test suite, so we don't load them every time.

Right now the best solution I have is to do something like this:

```
result = ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures("test/largefixtures", "web_sites")
rails_site = result[0].all_loaded_fixtures["web_sites"]["rubyonrails"].find
```

That seems rather brittle, not to mention I am not sure how to keep the create_fixtures result in scope in other places in the file.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote, the answer is in [fixtures.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord%2Flib%2Factive_record%2Ffixtures.rb#L905) with the `def setup_fixture_accessors(fixture_set_names = nil)` method.

You can see that a new module is created. The fixture accessors are added using `define_method` in the module. This way, `accessor_name` is then available and callable within the module.

Finally, `include methods`, includes all the methods of the Module `methods` defined above. Theses accessors are now available within the namespace calling `def fixtures(*fixture_set_names)` (usually `ActiveSupport::TestCase`)